# Зависает программа. C#

Tags: c#, .net, http

Имеется программа. Периодически зависает, не помогает ничего, т.е. только перезапуск. Место зависание в функции отправки запроса.

```
public async Task<string> PostRequestAsync(string url, string PostData, string Referer, CancellationToken ct)
{
    string Answer;
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    if (Proxy != null)
    {
        Request.Proxy = Proxy;
    }
    else
    {
        Request.Proxy = null;
    }
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.KeepAlive = true;
    Request.Timeout = 10000;
    Request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    Request.Host = BaseUrl.Substring(8);
    Request.KeepAlive = true;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData);
    Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    Request.Accept = "text/html, */*; q=0.01";
    Request.Headers.Add($"Origin: {BaseUrl}");
    Request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest");
    Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.168 Safari/537.36 OPR/51.0.2830.40";
    Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    Request.Referer = Referer;
    Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
    Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
    Request.CookieContainer = LoginData;
    try
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        using (Stream stream = await Request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse Response = await Request.GetResponseAsync();
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Answer = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        if (Answer.Contains("\\/site\\/logIn"))
        {
            Answer = "1";
            string html = await GetClearRequestAsync(BaseUrl, ct);
            var parser = new HtmlParser();
            var document = parser.Parse(html);
            string name = document.GetElementById("authentification").Children[1].GetAttribute("name").ToLower();
            string value = document.GetElementById("authentification").Children[1].GetAttribute("value").ToLower();
            string PostData1 = $"{name}={value}&login={login}&password={password}&redirection=&isBoxStyle=";
            await LoginRequestAsync(PostData1, ct);
        }
        Request.Abort();
        Response.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        Request.Abort();
        Answer = "0";
    }
    return Answer;
}
```

Пытался разбираться в сути проблемы. Было выявлено, что наиболее часто происходит такая проблема в двух случаях:
а) Плохое соединение с интернетом
б) Слабый ПК (ещё не совсем потверждено)
Случай "а" пытался исправить путем добавление цикла do while с проверкой на положительный ответ от сервера. Не вышло. Была мысль, что это связано с бесконечными попытками открытия соединения и добавил проверку такого рода

```
if(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
```

Тоже мимо. Теперь встал в тупик как же выявлять и присекать подобные случаи. Можно заметить что в функцию передается Cancellationtoken, отменить работу программы с его помощью не удаётся.

P.S. Работа возможно только с HttpWebRequest, остальные средства либо не подходят по удобству реализации, либо некорректно работают с сервером, стабильности добился только при таком подходе.

Comment: Ох, как у вас этот код вообще работает, смотреть прям больно на такое. У вас очень много лишнего, очень много не нужного, Есть места где и вовсе может упасть к примеру из за Null. Советую срочно провести рефакторинг!

Comment: Например? Вроде как обычный пример с оф. документации.

Comment: Ну пойдем по порядку `if (Proxy != null)` - зачем мы задаем null в прокси если он и так изначально не задан, от else (а то и вовсе от if можно отказаться). Далее `BaseUrl.Substring(8);` - Вам не кажется это странным? Здесь вы берете у string все после 8-го символа, это неверный подход! `KeepAlive` вы устанавливаете 2 раза. `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` - 3 раза. Часть заголовков можно вовсе убрать (я на 90% уверен, что к примеру `Accept-Language` тут вовсе не нужен). Теперь `document.GetElementById....` Что если `document` == null, а если `GetElementById` не нашел что надо, а `Children`?

Comment: Также сама логика, как по мне тут намешано все в одну кучу. Попробуйте разбить отправку запроса, проверку запроса и парсинг html по разным методам, у вас во много раз увеличится читаемость кода!

Comment: Благодарю за критику! Доберусь до дома постараюсь поправить. А про прокси где-то читал, что такой приём ускоряет выполнение запроса.

Comment: Не вижу где вы закрываете Response в случае ошибки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ множественные проверки ThrowIfCancellationRequested - не ошибка, потому что отмена может случиться в любой момент.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я не говорю, что это ошибка, я говорю, что используется 3 раза, когда можно все это написать более компактно и будет 1, максимум 2 раза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде трудно разобраться, но выглядит как будто вы никак не используете CancellationToken и не реализуете таймаут для сетевых операций. Для асинхронных сетевых операций, в отличие от синхронных, Request.Timeout играет роль только на начальном этапе от отправки заголовка до получения первых байт ответа. При обрыве связи на последующей загрузке они просто тихо умирают (никогда не заканчиваются), поэтому таймаут нужно реализовать вручную, как-то так:

```
static async Task<string> Download(string url)
{            
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var resp = await Request.GetResponseAsync();
        var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        using (stream)
        using (ms)
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var rd = new System.IO.StreamReader(ms);
            return await rd.ReadToEndAsync();
        }            
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    const string url = "http://example.com/";                    

    var res = await Task.WhenAny(Download(url),Task.Delay(10000));

    if (res is Task<string>) textBox1.Text = (res as Task<string>).Result;
    else textBox1.Text = "Timeout expired!";
}
```

Comment: Разве, по нажатию на кнопку не будет создана операция, которая будет задержана на 10к мс? А Request.Timeout ожидает ответа 10к мс, а потом считает, что соединение не удалось и выдаёт отрицательный ответ.

Comment: Все, суть уловил. Но разве это поможет от зависания? Ведь значение таймаута по дефолту стоит 100 секунд.

Comment: Так, теперь точно осмыслил концепт. Теперь остаётся вопрос почему так происходит, может я не совсем понимаю как работает таймаут.

Comment: @ВладимирКремлев `await Task.When` будет ждать завершения любой из указанных задач. Да, это должно помочь от зависания независимо от значения Request.Timeout.

Comment: @ВладимирКремлев Потому, что так спроектирован API. Из документации (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2): `In the case of asynchronous requests, the client application implements its own time-out mechanism.`